# How do you display raw html code in vue if you dont want it to be rendered like a component

Tags: vue.js

How do you display raw code in `vue`?

For example I have a `<Button />`. Putting that in my template renders the component. What do i  do if i just want to render the text as you see it `<Button />`? I tried double mustache (`{{ <Button /> }}`) and that  still renders the component. Do i have to install a markdown library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution is to replace `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <pre>&lt;Button /&gt;</pre>
  </div>
</template>
```

Another solution is to create a string in your `data` property and render it in your template, since it will be rendered as plain text, as per [Vue's documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML):

> The double mustaches interprets the data as plain text, not HTML. In
> order to output real HTML, you will need to use the v-html directive

So, by doing the opposite, because you want to render the HTML as plain text, the following example will work:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    {{ htmlRenderedAsText }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        htmlRenderedAsText: "<Button />"
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```